# collections.binarySearch() is not working with comparable

Tags: comparator, comparable

After sorting List in ascending and descending order i want to invoke binarySearch method.
But it not working as i have implemented comparable.

```
 class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
private int id;
private String name;

public Student(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {

    int j = o.getId();
    int result = this.id - j;
    return result;
}


}
public class CollectionSearchDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(new Student(3, "ouier"));
    list.add(new Student(2, "fdgds"));
    list.add(new Student(7, "kiluf"));
    list.add(new Student(1, "6trfd"));
    list.add(new Student(8, "hjgas"));
    list.add(new Student(5, "ewwew"));

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {

            return arg0.getId() - arg1.getId();
        }
    });

    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Student student = (Student) iterator.next();
        System.out.print(student.getId()+":"+student.getName()+" ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nSorting in reverse order:");

//  Collections.reverse(list);
    Comparator<Student> collections = Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(list, collections);

    Iterator iterator1 = list.iterator();
    while(iterator1.hasNext()){
        Student student = (Student) iterator1.next();
        System.out.print(student.getId()+":"+student.getName()+" ");
    }

    System.out.println("I want to do searching ");
    System.out.println("\n2 is at:"+Collections.binarySearch(list, 2, new Student()));
            // facing exception at this line.I don't know what to use as argument of                           binarySearch() method. 
}

}
```

I could have done this by implementing comparator but i have such requirement in my project
Please guide me.

Comment: You have deleted the end of your method call: `Collections.binary`

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of Collections.binarySearch:

> The list must be sorted into **ascending order** according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.